# FileMaker PHP API - why is the initial connection so slow?

Tags: php, filemaker

I've just set up my first remote connection with FileMaker Server using the PHP API and something a bit strange is happening.

The first connection and response takes around 5 seconds, if I hit reload immediately afterwards, I get a response within 0.5 second.

I can get a quick response for around 60 seconds or so (not timed it yet but it seems like at least a minute but less than 5 minutes) and then it goes back to taking 5 seconds to get a response. (after that it's quick again)

Is there any way of ensuring that it's always a quick response?

Comment: Sounds like something is caching...

Comment: Or FileMaker’s script for authentication is really slow. I would get in touch with them just to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you an exact answer on where the speed difference may be coming from, but I'd agree with NATH's notion on caching. It's likely due to how FileMaker Server handles caching the results on the server side and when it clears that cache out.

In addition to that, a couple of things that are helpful to know when using custom web publishing with FileMaker when it comes to speed:

### The fields on your layout will determine how much data is pulled

When you perform a find in the PHP api on a specific layout, e.g.:

```
$request = $fm->newFindCommand('myLayout');
$request->addFindCriterion('name', $myname);
$result = $request->execute();
```

What's being returned is data from all of the fields available on the `my layout` layout.

In sql terms, the above query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM myLayout WHERE `name` = ?; // and the $myname variable is bound to ?
```

The FileMaker find will return every field/column available. You designate the returned columns by placing the fields you want on the layout. To get a true `*` select all from your table, you would include every field from the table on your layout.

All of that said, you can speed up your requests by only including fields on the layout that you want returned in the queries. If you only need data from 3 fields returned to your php to get the job done, only include those 3 fields on the layout the requests use.

### Once you have the records, hold on to them so you can edit them

Taking the example from above, if you know you need to make changes to those records somewhere down the line in your php, store the records in a variable and use the `setField` and `commit` methods to edit them. e.g.:

```
$request = $fm->newFindCommand('my layout');
$request->addFindCriterion('name', $myname);
$result = $request->execute();
$records = $result->getRecords();
...
// say we want to update a flag on each of the records down the line in our php code
foreach($records as $record){
    $record->setField('active', true);
    $record->commit();
}
```

Since you have the records already, you can act on them and commit them when needed.

I say this as opposed to grabbing them once for one purpose and then grabbing them again from the database later do make updates to the records.

It's not really an answer to your original question, but since FileMaker's API is a bit different than others and it doesn't have the greatest documentation I though I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's related to caching.  Also, it's the same when accessing via XML.  Haven't tested ODBC, but am assuming that it is an issue with this too.

Once the connection is established with FileMaker Server and your machine, FileMaker Server keeps this connection alive for about 3 minutes.  You can see the connection in the client list in the FM Server Admin Console.  The initial connection takes a few seconds to set up (depending on how many others are connected), and then ANY further queries are lightning fast.  If you run your app again, it'll reuse that connection and give results in very little time.

You can do completely different queries (on different tables) in a different application, but as long as you execute the second one on the same machine and use the same credentials, FileMaker Server will reuse the existing connection and provide results instantly.  This means that it is not due to caching, but it's just the time that it takes FMServer to initially establish a connection.

In our case, we're using a web server to make FileMaker PHP API calls.  We have set up a cron every 2 minutes to keep that connection alive, which has pretty much eliminated all delays.

Answer (score 0):

There are some delays that you can remove.
Ensure that the layouts you are accessing via PHP are very simple, no unnecessary or slow calculations, few layout objects etc.  When the PHP engine first accesses that layout it needs to load it up.
Also check for layout and file script triggers that may be run, IIRC the OnFirstWindowOpen script trigger is called when a connection is made.

Comment: Just to clarify something here - in Custom Web Publishing solutions the OnFirstWindowOpen script trigger is not activated

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way late to answer this, but I'm posting here in case anyone else sees this.

I've seen this happen when using external authentication with FileMaker Server. The first query establishes a connection to Active Directory, which takes some time, and then subsequent queries are fast as FMS has got the authentication figured out. If you can, use local authentication in your FileMaker file for your PHP access and make sure it sits above any external authentication in your accounts list. FileMaker runs through the auth list from top to bottom, so this will make sure that FMS successfully authenticates your web query before it gets to attempt an external authentication request, making the authentication process very fast.